# No Mocha monkey-patch for MiniTest version (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

Any idea how to fix this.. this has happened recently when I try to open my rails console (both development and production). I saw a bug report. But any temporary fix?

```
lib/mocha/integration/mini_test.rb:56:in `<class:TestCase>': No Mocha monkey-patch for MiniTest version (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mocha-0.12.6/lib/mocha/integration/mini_test.rb:20:in `<class:Unit>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mocha-0.12.6/lib/mocha/integration/mini_test.rb:19:in `<module:MiniTest>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mocha-0.12.6/lib/mocha/integration/mini_test.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mocha-0.12.6/lib/mocha/integration.rb:45:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mocha-0.12.6/lib/mocha/integration.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mocha-0.12.6/lib/mocha/integration.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mocha-0.12.6/lib/mocha.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/testing/mochaing.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `block in silence_warnings'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:22:in `with_warnings'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/testing/mochaing.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:299:in `initialize_console'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/carlos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured, I can use a previous version of minitest for this to work

```
gem 'minitest', '3.5.0'
```